# HTML5 DrawImage Broken on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

The following code works on Chrome for Windows but fails to draw anything to canvas on Chrome for Android. I have CORS implemented properly on the server. Any ideas?

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
identicon.onload = function() {
    ctx.canvas.width = img .width;
    ctx.canvas.height = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(img ,0,0)
}
img.src = "http://urltoimage";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Bitmap which Chrome on Android does not support. Switched to PNG and it was fine.